# Setting conditions in arrays in SAS

Tags: arrays, count, sas

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
ID  Status31Jan2007 Status28Jan2007 Status31Mar2007
001                        0               0             
002        1               0               0
003        1               1               0
```

I have Statusddmmyyyy fields of either '0' or '1' for 118 months. (here, I only have three months as a sample)

I want to get results like this:

```
ID       Flag1           Flag2           Flag3 
001        N               N               N            
002        Y               N               N
003        Y               Y               N
```

The logic is, if as at Status31Jan2007 = 1 and the following two months, count of Status fields with 0 > 0, then flag it as 'Y'. Else, N.

Meaning, 
If my ID is 001 and as at Status31Jan2007, value is missing, i flag it as 'N' under Flag1. 
Moving on to the next month, Status28Feb2007, value is 0, i automatically flag it as 'N' as well under Flag2. This applies to the next month.

Looking at ID 002, Status31Jan2007 is 1. And following two months, I have two 0 values. Count of '0' value is > 0. So I flag it as 'Y' under Flag1.
But as at Status28Feb2007, it is 0. It doesnt fit the criteria so i flag it as 'N' under Flag2.

As long as as at the field, I need the status to be 1 then only I proceed to look into the following two months.

After getting the results, how do I count the number of flags N and Y under each fields?

```
        Count1           Count2          Count3
N          1               2               3 
Y          2               1               0
```

Would appreciate the help as I am new to SAS. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the logic, does the value you want for each column depend upon the values in the next 2 columns, and if that is the case then how would the last 2 columns be calculated. Perhaps explain how the values you have shown that you want have been calculated, e.g. why is `Flag1`=N in the first observation and so on.

Comment: I have explained a little bit further. Hope it is much clearer! :)

Comment: The value for the first column depends upon the values the following two columns. And the 2nd column would depend on the next two columns and so on.

Comment: Thanks. So as I understand it, you only want to look at the next two columns if the current column is `1`. Two questions: (1) What is the logic for the last 2 columns, as you can't look ahead 2 columns? (2) Is there a pattern to the column names and if yes then what is the pattern?

Comment: To reply to your questions, (1) for the 2nd column, i'll look at the last column. for the last column, i would expect my result to be flagged as 'N' as I can't look ahead anymore. (2) for my current dataset, my column names would be just Status31Jan2007 - Status 31Oct2016. I can rename this to Status1-Status118 if it's easier. for my output, it'll be under a different name so maybe, Flag1-Flag118. Is this the pattern that you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work if the column names across are in calendar order.

Use an `ARRAY` statement to organize and then access variables by index and thus easily process the [index+1] and [index+2] checks your logic indicates.  You can also use temporary arrays to maintain a count as you assign the flag values; at the last row the counts are output to a separate table.

Note: for status variables taking on either 0 or 1 the count of 1's can be computed using `SUM`. The sum of two status variables will be < 2 when either of them is 0.

```
* simulate some data;
data prelim;
  do id = 1 to 20;
    do date = '01jan07'd by 1 until(intck('month', '01jan07'd, date) >= 117);
      date = intnx('month', date, 1) - 1;
      status = ranuni(123) < 0.45;
      if date = '31jan07'd and mod(id,5) = 1 then status = .;
      output;
    end;
  end;
  format date date9.;
run;

* change the shape of simulated data to match the question;
proc transpose data=prelim prefix=Status out=have(drop=_name_);
  by id;
  var status;
  id date;
run;

* process the problem shaped data;    
data
  want (keep=id status: flag:)
  want_count (keep=flag_value count:);
;
  set have end=lastid;

  retain sentinel1 sentinel2 0;

  array status status: sentinel1 sentinel2;  * map all the Status* variables to an array named status;
  array flag [118] $1 ; * automatically creates 118 new variables flag1 to flag118;
  array yfreq [118] _temporary_ (118*0); * temporary arrays initialized to 0;
  array nfreq [118] _temporary_ (118*0);

  * process each month status, -2 because of the sentinels ;
  do i = 1 to dim(status)-2;

    * assign flag according to the logic, some cases require a 2-month look ahead;
    select;
      when ( status(i) = . ) flag(i) = 'N';
      when ( status(i) = 0 ) flag(i) = 'N';
      when ( status(i) = 1 
             and sum(status(i+1),status(i+2)) < 2 ) flag(i) = 'Y';  * SUM trick;
      otherwise
        flag(i) = 'N';
    end;

    * track frequencies of flags assigned;
    if flag(i) = 'N'
      then nfreq(i)+1;
      else yfreq(i)+1;
  end;

  output want;

  if lastid then do;
    * all flags for all ids have been binned for frequency;
    * output the freqs to a count data set;
    length flag_value $1;
    array freq count1-count118;
    flag_value = 'N'; do i = 1 to dim(nfreq); freq(i) = nfreq(i); end; output want_count;
    flag_value = 'Y'; do i = 1 to dim(yfreq); freq(i) = yfreq(i); end; output want_count;
  end;
run;
```